# Can I embed wxPython in my project, saving users the trouble of installing it?

Tags: python, wxpython

I recently discovered how easy and convenient using wxPython is for writing GUI applications. Unfortunately installing wxPython is a giant throbbing pain in the neck. I consider myself pretty tech-savvy but it took me almost an hour to get a working setup of wxPython on a Pythonbrew install on an Ubuntu machine. On my OSX machine at home I still haven't figured it out.

So my question is; is it possible, somehow, to install a **portable** version of wxPython and place it in my project directory where it will work on all platforms, saving users the pain of having to manually install it to run my application? If yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: Are you using `cx_freeze` or `py2exe` for your project?

Comment: If installing `foo` is a pain, then attempting to embed the installation of `foo` with your project will make installing your project a pain for any `foo`.  And you inherit a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Nope, it's just a plain Python project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wx has to be compiled for each target plattform. Binaries are always OS dependent, so no, there cannot be a portable wx version.

Comment: What if I just have 3 target platforms? Is it impossible to have precompiled binaries for those three platforms embedded in the platform?

Comment: If you are willing to create separate packages for each plattform, it's a completly differnt question. You will probalby not be able to embed wx in your library, but for windows you could for example look at http://wiki.wxpython.org/DistributingYourApplication But for Windows and OS X you can use existing installers, so no need to compile anything. Don't know about Linux.

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller is supposed to make things easy on the 3 major platforms. I've only used it on Windows though. cx_freeze and bb_freeze may also help you. There's a py2app script that is ONLY for Macs.

If you're having trouble installing wxPython on Mac, then you should ask on the wxPython mailing list. There are several Mac users on there, including the author of wxPython himself.

If you want portable, then you might check out the Portable Python project: http://www.portablepython.com/ I'm pretty sure it includes wxPython.